# Can Python context managers be used with generators?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager, generator-expression

I'm trying to use a context manager which controls visiting a subdirectory, and it seems like it would be very elegant to combine that with a generator expression, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to correct this so I can use the two together?

Here's the example:

```
import os, sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
from glob import glob
 
@contextmanager
def visitDir(d):
    os.chdir(d)
    yield d
    os.chdir("..")
 
paths = [os.path.join('.', p[0:-1]) for p in glob('*/')]
 
def clean():
    for p in (visitDir(p) for p in paths): # This is the magic line
    print(p)
    print(os.getcwd())
 
clean() # Context manager apparently expires within the generator expression
```

Comment: I replaced *stream* with *generator expression*; *stream* is not a concept that applies to this.

Comment: Does the generator expression not create a stream, though -- the evaluation only happens every time a new object is fetched, rather than all up front as with a list expression?

Comment: Python calls the general concept an iterator. Iterators produce one value at a time, when prompted. A generator expression is syntax to produce a generator in a compact manner, where a generator is a specialised kind of iterator. You *could* call the result a stream, but that's not a term Python uses anywhere for this concept.

Comment: I was working from [this article](http://radimrehurek.com/2014/03/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/) which seems to use "stream" fairly freely.

Comment: Also from [here in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions). Am I misunderstanding the terminology they use?

Comment: Both explain the workings of an iterator as a stream; it's an analogy more than the label for the concept. More generally the term is used in the context of [I/O (so files and sockets and pipes)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to control the entering and leaving of a context. The generator expression has no concept of a wider context, so you cannot just put a context manager in a generator expression and expect that to be automatically entered when yielded.

Only the `with` statement manages the actual context, triggering the `__enter__` and `__exit__` hooks on the CM. You can just use the produced context manager objects from the generator expression here:

```
def clean():
    for cm in (visitDir(p) for p in paths):
        with cm as p:
            print p
            print os.getcwd()
```

The `with` statement calls `cm.__enter__` here, and when the block is complete `cm.__exit__` is called.

But I'd find the following more readable and comprehensible:

```
def clean():
    for p in paths:
        with visitDir(p):
            print p
            print os.getcwd()
```

because creating the context manager as part of the `with` line is just easier to follow.